# Spring MVC custom authorization/security for controller methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Looking to create a custom implementation to authorize requests.

I am evaluating options to avoid using annotations on every method in  the controller.
Instead, I am exploring the possibility centralizing this feature via a filter that checks if the logged in user has the required permission for the URL

We are using Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE

I intend to create a database table that has a mapping between a permission and the relevant URL.

I am looking for a way to get the request mapping information for the current URL.

For E-g :
In my database, I have:

```
    URL=/view/{id} , permission=VIEW_USER
```

If the current URL is :

```
    /app/user/view/1
```

, a method annotated with

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/view/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

will be invoked. But before this happens, I need to verify if the logged in user has the permission to view user details.

In my filter, I can get the current URL (`/app/user/view/1`) , how do I get the corresponding mapping (`/view/{id}`) ? Is there a mechanism to match a URL to its corresponding MVC request mapping ?

I have looked/am looking at related posts on SO and also looked at Spring code but am yet to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it that way, you could register MVC interceptor instead of servlet filter.
Create a class that extends `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and in preHandle method you will have access to controller's method and it's annotation. Prehandle method of your interceptor could look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        if (method.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            RequestMapping rqm = method.getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            String[] urlMappings = rqm.value();
            //do security logic
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you need to register the interceptor. If you use xml config it's done like this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.example.MySecurityInterceptor" />
  ...
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Please note that your approach will be difficult, you'll need to handle all the request mapping cases that spring supports. For example, `@RequestMapping` that's annotated on class level. Or `@RequestMapping` annotated on parent class of the controller etc..

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. You made a good point about handling different situations. If I can figure out how to match a URL to its corresponding request mapping I might be able to do something. Spring MVC must be doing that right. There must be a mechanism that matches URLs to a Request mapping so that a controller method is invoked, it might help if I can figure that out.